# How to retrieve data which returns from a servlet after I sent it with a httpPost in Android

Tags: java, android, servlets, callback, http-post

I send my object for saving in a database to HttpServlet using a HttpPost. But after I saved it on the Server side, I need to take it with its corresponding id. So how can I do that?

```
Gson gson = GsonFactory.getInstance();
String json1;
String url;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

url = this.url + "/saveMyOrder";
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("process", "save"));
Order object = new Order();
object.setName("Order");
object.setTime(new Date());
json1 = gson.toJson(object);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json1));

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse response = HttpOperations.httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success ... ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("ERROR!").setCancelable(true);
        dlgAlert.show();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried to convert my code to English, so if you don't understand something, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my questions after [my research](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-http-response-body-as-a-string/). The answer is:

String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

it returns your data as string after you post it.